# Canonical form and fundamental solution of pdf

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Can someone help with these two PDE problems? Thank you.

Reduce to Canonical form and find the fundamental solution if possible.

$$y^2u_{xx} + x^2u_{yy} = 0.$$

What type of transformation should I choose??

Answer (score 0):

Separation of variables $u(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$.

$y^2 X''(x)Y(y)+x^2 X(x)Y''(y)=0$

$\displaystyle \frac{Y''(y)}{y^{2} Y(y)}=-\frac{X''(x)}{x^{2} X(x)}=-\frac{k^{4}}{4}$

$\displaystyle X(x)=a\, D_{-\frac{1}{2}}(kx)+b\, D_{-\frac{1}{2}}(ikx)$

$\displaystyle Y(y)=
c\, D_{-\frac{1}{2}} \left(  \frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}} ky \right)+
d\, D_{-\frac{1}{2}} \left( -\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}} ky \right)$

where $D_{\nu}(t)$ is parabolic cylinder function satisfying 
$\displaystyle z''+\left( \nu +\frac{1}{2}-\frac{t^{2}}{4} \right)z=0$

Answer (score 0):

The equation can be classified as being *elliptic*. The procedure to transform the equation to canonical form can be found [here](http://www.math.psu.edu/wysocki/M412/Notes412_5.pdf). I advise you to follow that procedure and, if you do not succeed in finding a fundamental solution based on the new canonical form of the equation, post a new question on this site.